# Order directory by a date string of a file inside this directory

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, directory

I'm having a headache with this.
I'm trying to order a number of directories by a file which is within this directory which contains the creation date of the backup.

This is for order my backups, i can't do this with the ctime or atime of the directory because they are copied to other host at the same time.

Let's say I have the next structure:

```
/backups/full
/backups/incremental1
/backups/incremental2
/backups/incremental3
...
```

And inside those backup directories, we have:

```
/backups/full/date.txt
/backups/incremental1/date.txt
/backups/incremental2/date.txt
..
```

And inside that `date.txt` file we have a string as: `creation_time = 2020-04-03 15:26:19` for each one.

How could I make a script to order this directories by their creation_time string and put them in an array, so i could do a

```
array=(full incremental1 incremental2 incremental3)
```

`for dir in @{array[@]}; do`

I woul like to have them ordered inside a variable or an array

Comment: You mean output a list of directories by that order ?

Comment: Exactly, because if I order the directories by something as executing `ls -ltu` i get a list as `incremental1 full incremental2 ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the structure of `date.txt` is always the same and the directory names don't contain newlines, something like this should do the trick:

```bsh
for d in /backups/*/date.txt; do
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$(grep creation_time "$d")" "$(basename "$(dirname "$d")")"
done | sort | cut -f2-
```

Output:

```
full
incremental1
incremental2
incremental3
```

How to put this in an array should be fairly easy, but probably you won't need that as you could feed the result into e.g. a `while` loop or `xargs` or alike.

Comment: Works perfectly. The data.txt file also has more lines but i just put a `grep creation_time` inside the $(cat "$d") and it displays the directories ordered. Thanks!!

Comment: @arthur You may want to look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, and also take the tour: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour (you'll receive a badge when you've done so).

Answer (score 0):

Working with the last-modified timestamp of the `date.txt` files in the `zsh` shell:

```
for backupdir in /backup/*/date.txt(ome['REPLY=$REPLY:h']); do
    # do whatever you need to do
    # with the directory path in $backupdir
done
```

This uses a globbing pattern to match all the `date.txt` files.  The globbing qualifier at the end of the pattern sorts the matches so that the most recently modified match is first (this is what `om` does), and removes the `/date.txt` string from the matching pathname (like `dirname` would do).

This is obviously assuming that the `date.txt` files were updated when the date was written to the file (at around the same time when the backup was made). This timestamp (as well as the directory timestamps) would be preserved if you copy the data using `rsync --archive`.

From `bash`:

```
zsh -c '
for backupdir in /backup/*/date.txt(ome['\''REPLY=$REPLY:h'\'']); do
    # do whatever you need to do
    # with the directory path in $backupdir
done'
```